# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'EmbeddedModelField'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, djongo

I am connecting Django up to a MongoDB where there are embedded documents. I followed the documentation on https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/. However, I am recieving the error "module "django.db.models' has no attribute 'EmbeddedModelField"

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime

class Code(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    purchasePrice = models.FloatField(default=1, blank=False, null=False)
    datetimeBuy = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=65, default="", blank=False, null=False)
    codes = models.EmbeddedModelField(model_container=Code,)
```

**Stack trace**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x043D9ED0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WebApps\Django\StockView\backend\src\portfolio\models.py", line 25, in <module>
    class Portfolio(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WebApps\Django\StockView\backend\src\portfolio\models.py", line 29, in Portfolio
    codes = models.EmbeddedModelField(model_container=Code,)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'EmbeddedModelField'
```

Thank you.

Comment: It should be `djongo.models` instead of `django.db.models`...

Comment: Good spot. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. before djongo 1.3.1 there was 'EmbeddedModelField', after that this has been converted to 'EmbeddedField'

   2.Now it will give you error like "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet."

   so downgrade the djongo from default 1.3.2 to 1.3.1